# Needing a formula to calculate and return the result but leave blank if cell is NA

Tags: excel

I have a spreadsheet I'm working on presently, and I need a formula that does the following:

I want E7 to add 7 days to D7 so 20/04/20 = 27/04/20. but if NA is entered in D7 i want E7 to show NA as well.

I have so far tried the following formula

```
=IFERROR(D7+7,"NA")
```

The above gets me close but it then shows the number 7 in all cells of E7 I don't want that to happen and want the formula to not do anything unless the cells of column D have a date entered into them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In E7 put this formula:

```
=IF(D7="","",IFERROR(D7+7,D7))
```

[image: ![enter image description here]